# Is there a way to add friends instantly on a mobile device through QR-codes?

Tags: facebook, qr-code

I want to know if there's a way to let people add me instantly with a QR code.

I know that I can just make a QR with the link to my FB account, but I'd like to know if it's possible to actually open the FB app on the phone automaticcaly when scanning, and then add me.

So via the FB app would be the best way, but it would also be acceptable if I can just make a link where the user will automatically add me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it for iPhone, but it seems there is no consistant way to do it for all mobile platforms.

iPhone understands "custom URLs" like fb://profile/xxxx so by encoding it in your QR code you can send user to your profile page, where he/she will add you.

More details on fb:// URL scheme
http://iphonedevtools.com/?p=302
http://mobileorchard.com/opening-the-facebook-app-to-your-facebook-fan-page/

There is an app for Android that can do similar thing - 
http://fastgush.com/facebook/android-app-uses-qr-code-to-add-facebook-friends.html